# Correcting a Java Program Code Fragment

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner level of studying java and revising for my exams through answering the questions on previous past exam papers and there is one question that I am stuck on.

**Consider the code fragment below that reads an input command then processes it.**

```
String cmd = scanner.next();

if (cmd == "forward" )
    robot.forward(1);
else if (cmd == "turn" ) 
    robot.turn();
else
     System.out.println("Unknown command: " + cmd);
```

**When testing the program the scanner reads in the String "forward" into cmd, but the program outputs "Unknown command: forward".**

**a) Explain, in detail, why this occurs.**

**b) What changes should be made to the code to correct this error.**

If someone can help me answer question **a)** and **b)** I would be grateful.

p.s. I understand that this isn't a website to just look for answers (#noeasywayout) so I'm going to try my best not to act greedy here. My apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: So have you tried the code? Do you have *any* ideas yet?

Comment: Just to point you to the direction, you cannot compare `String`s with `==`. It is better for you to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*This old chestnut...*

In java, `==` tests if the two operands are the *exact same object*, which obviously they are not (one of the objects is a String constant, the other was read from input).

Use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to compare their *value*.

Try this:

```
if (cmd.equals("forward"))
    robot.forward(1);
else if (cmd.equals("turn")) 
    robot.turn();
else
    System.out.println("Unknown command: " + cmd);
```

BTW, with this pattern of code, beware calling `.equals()` on `cmd` if it is `null` - you'll get a [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). A common way to avoid this without adding any code is to use a "yoda test" (one with a "reversed" logic):

```
if ("forward".equals(cmd))
    robot.forward(1);
else if ("turn".equals(cmd)) 
    robot.turn();
else
    System.out.println("Unknown command: " + cmd);
```

This code won't throw an [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if `cmd` is `null`

Comment: @hmjd Yoda it *is*, not joda. Correct you are!

Answer (score 2):

Try cmd.equalsIgnorecase or cmd.equals instead of ==.

```
String cmd = scanner.next();

if (cmd.equals("forward") )
   robot.forward(1);
else if (cmd.equals("turn") ) 
   robot.turn();
else
 System.out.println("Unknown command: " + cmd);
```

The reason being String is a object and when you use the == it does object comparison.

Comment: Sure you can compare an object to a String. A String is an object too.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was typing to fast. I meant the == is used for Object comparison not for string comparison.

Comment: Fixed and time to go home and have a coffee.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this section in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html):

> 15.21.3 Reference Equality Operators == and !=
>
> While == may be used to compare references of type String, such an equality test determines whether or not the two operands refer to the same String object. The result is false if the operands are distinct String objects, even if they contain the same sequence of characters. The contents of two strings s and t can be tested for equality by the method invocation s.equals(t).